# Console Application Persistent Error does not contain static main method suitable for entry point

Tags: c#

Firstly to say I have read up on the similar questions and I have tried everything. At a total loss at this stage. The error message is as follows:

> Error 1   Program 'C:\Users\epm\Desktop\c# work\Projects\ConsoleApplication10\ConsoleApplication10\obj\x86\Debug\ConsoleApplication10.exe' does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point

Then another notice pops up after I try to run it despite the build error which says:

> Visual Studio cannot start debugging because the debug target 'C:\Users\epm\Desktop\c#work\Projects\ConsoleApplication10\ConsoleApplication10\bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication10.exe' is missing. Please build the project and retry, or set the OutputPath and AssemblyName properties appropriately to point at the correct location for the target assembly.

I've spent many hours trying every solution I could find on the internet and I would be so grateful if anyone could help me out. Thank you.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication10
{
    class Program
    {

        static void main()
        {
            List<Student> list = new List<Student>();
            list.Add(new Student() { Name = "Alan", Grade = 100 });
            list.Add(new Student() { Name = "Jane", Grade = 100 });
            list.Add(new Student() { Name = "Aidan", Grade = 90 });
            list.Add(new Student() { Name = "Bill", Grade = 50 });
            list.Add(new Student() { Name = "Liam", Grade = 80 });

            list.Sort();

            foreach (var element in list)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(element);
            }
        }

        class Student : IComparable<Student>
        {
            public int Grade { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }

            public int CompareTo(Student other)
            {
                if (this.Grade == other.Grade)
                {
                    return this.Name.CompareTo(other.Name);
                }

                else return other.Grade.CompareTo(this.Grade);
            }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return this.Grade.ToString() + "," + this.Name;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `static void Main()` - Capital M

Comment: Case sensitive big Main not little main...

Comment: My word, I am a proper eejit. Thanks very much. I really appreciate you taking a look.

Comment: It's also [best practice](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0(v=vs.71).aspx) if all your methods are [Capitalized](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4df752aw(v=vs.71).aspx).

Comment: @epMorgs Mark someones answer as accepted please, to get this out of the queue's.

Comment: It's telling me I have to wait 7 minutes. Will do it asap.

Comment: The easiest way that I could see that you could have solved this issue on your own would have been to open up another instance of visual studio, create a dummy console app, and then in the main section you would have quickly spotted your problem meaning that the syntax for the Main method's entry point should look like this `static void Main(string[] args)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main method of a C# program typically looks like:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When building a project in C#, the main method is written like this:

```
static void Main(){...}
```

*Please note the capital "M" in "Main".*

In Java, the main method is written with a lowercase "m" if that is what you were thinking.

Answer (score 0):

If in doubt, simply create a new console application with the "new project -> c# console application" wizard and you can see.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Main with a capital M and string[] args is what the wizard generates.